# Comparing two Lists and returning the distinct values and the differences

Tags: linq, list, c#-4.0, duplicates

I have two lists:

```
List A {A, B, C, D}

List B {A, E, F, G}
```

I need to produce three lists:

One with the items only in list A

(B, C, D)

One with the items only in list B

(E, F, G)

One with the items in both

(A)

Given that the lists are actually registry keys, there could be a huge number of them so I can foresee a huge performance overhead if I choose to use traditional ForEach or For(int i...) methods.

I am not averse to these if they will do the job efficiently but I would prefer to use Linq.

Has anyone got any ideas?

I don't care about identical records.

I have already created an `IEquatable<>` class that will compare the elements, but it is how to use this to create my required outputs that I am struggling with.

Thanks in advance.

By the way I am using VS2012 with .NET 4.5

Comment: Show us the classes involved.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var A = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var B = new List<string>() { "A", "E", "F", "G" };

A.Except(B).ToList()
// outputs List<string>(2) { "B", "C", "D" }
B.Except(A).ToList()
// outputs List<string>(2) { "E", "F", "G" }
B.Intersect(A).ToList()
// outputs List<string>(2) { "A" }
```

Comment: Technically the OP is wrong, B is only in list A and E is only in list B, so the two Except are different :-)

Comment: oops, output from B = A, B, F, G, wrong init in my code. Changed output :) sry for that

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have read my example before I posted (D'oh!) anyway thanks these seem like exactly what I need!

Comment: Correct way as follows ....  //Unique from two list
            var A = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 };
            var B = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 6, 7 };

           var a= A.Except(B).ToList();
            // outputs List<int>(2) { 2,3,4 }
           var b= B.Except(A).ToList();
            // outputs List<int>(2) { 5,6,7 }
           var abint=  B.Intersect(A).ToList();
            // outputs List<int>(2) { 1 }

Answer (score 6):

Using **LINQ**

```
listA.Except(listB)
```

This will give you all of the items in listA that are not in listB..

For **similar**

```
listA.SequenceEqual(listB)
```