# Subtract a generic list from another

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying remove a list of firmIDs from one list from another.
I don't really understand linq but I am pretty sure I need to use it.

```
List<Firm> firms = GetBusinessDevelopmentFirms(database);
List<Firm> trackedFirms = GetAllCLIFirmsBeingTrackedByUser();

var result = firms.Contains(i => trackedFirms.Contains(i.FirmID));
```

The last line doesn't work and the system says "unknown method Contains(?)" even though I have put "using System.Linq;" At the top of the class.

My idea was to remove a list of tracked firms from a list of all firms to find the untracked firms.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
var result = firms.Except(trackedFirms); // returns all the firms except those in trackedFirms
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that you banking on the same actual instances of Firm being held in both lists...

Comment: Not that it really matters, but it should be noted that this is not Linq, but an existing [method on List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908822(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Cheers for the heads up, if I don't have to use Linq that's fine. I will get my head around it one day. I will mark this as my answer when the site allows me to. Cheers all

Comment: You are right. But please note that the compiler actually converts the linq queries to the corresponding Extension Methods. So no that much difference between them. Also, the last line of OP questions implies what he wants.

Comment: @RGraham No, you just linked to the Linq method, you just linked to it from the section of extension methods on the `List<T>` page.  `List<T>` has no instance `Except` method.  If you select one of the overloads on that page you'll see the namespace they're defined in is `System.Linq` and that the first parameter is `IEnumerable<T>` not `List<T>`.

Comment: @Servy You're right - I did not see the extension icon on that page :)

Comment: @MartinMilan I think, rather banking on Firm having it's equality method/operator overloaded to be meaningful for this purpose; giving Firms an identity other than object reference equality.

Comment: @Alireza This will give distinct values of `firm`. What if you don't want it to give you the distinct values of firm and if there are any values in firm that are repeating, give them as repeated?

Comment: Don't forget to include IEqulityComparer<T> as second parameter if class is a complex one.

Answer (score 15):

From your code above, I presume you are trying to get entries from Firms that have a corresponding item in TrackedFirms.

```
List<Firm> results = Firms.Where(f => TrackedFirms.Any(t => t.FirmId == f.FirmId)).ToList();
```

If on the other hand you want untracked firms, then it's :

```
List<Firm> results = Firms.Where(f => !TrackedFirms.Any(t => t.FirmId == f.FirmId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this should works

```
var result = firms.Where(x => !trackedFirms.Any(y => x.FirmID == y.FirmID));
```

From all the firm in `firms` select the firm that **isn't** in the `trackedFirms` (at least this is what i understand from your question).

Answer (score 5):

The best approach would be `Except()` for you case. However, if the List object is different then other one, you can use `All()`

```
firms.Where(x=> trackedFirms.All(y => y.FirmId != x.FirmId)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Contains` is the native method of `List<T>` that expects you to pass in a `T`.  You want `Where` instead.

```
var result = firms.Where(i => trackedFirms.Contains(i.FirmID));
```

If you expect `result` to be a `List<T>` then add `.ToList()` to the end of your `Where` LINQ expression.

Comment: While my answer is most closely related to your question, I really prefer this answer to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18895816/1795053 If you just add `.ToList()` to his, you'll get the same results.  Or if you prefer to know the Intersection, then one of the `Intersect` results.  It's more precise and more obvious what your goal is.  I'd consider accepting one of their answers.  Good luck!

Comment: 1) This is the intersection of the two lists, not the subtraction of one from the other. 2) You're doing a linear search for each item, which is much slower than it could be if using a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have list X and a list Y, and you want to remove all items in Y that are in X you can experiment with the following:

X.Intersect(Y)

[Comparing two Lists and returning the distinct values and the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099054/comparing-two-lists-and-returning-the-distinct-values-and-the-differences)

Comment: Intersect isn't set subtraction.