# Remove specific items from list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of objects:

```
public class SDesc
{
    public string sensorId { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

List<SDesc> desc = new List<SDesc>
{
    new SDesc {sensorId = "1234", address =   "Adams22"},
    new SDesc {sensorId = "5555", address =   "Hourton34"},
    new SDesc {sensorId = "4444", address =   "SaintsRoad55"},
    new SDesc {sensorId = "1258", address =   "BerryAve58"},
    new SDesc {sensorId = "52486", address =   "SaintsRoad2"},
    new SDesc {sensorId = "12361", address =   "TomassonRoad"}
}
```

And also I have IEnumarable of strings:

```
IEnumarable<string> sId = {"4444","52486","12361"};
```

from **desc** list I need to remove records where sensorsId property exists in sId list.

For example for case above the result I want to get is:

```
List<SDesc> desc = new List<SDesc>
{
    new SDesc {sensorId = "1234", address =   "Adams22"},
    new SDesc {sensorId = "5555", address =   "Hourton34"},
    new SDesc {sensorId = "1258", address =   "BerryAve58"},
}
```

Here what I tried:

```
desc.RemoveAll(obj => obj.sensorId == sId);
```

But it's not works properly because sID is IEnumarable type.

So my question  is how to remove items from **desc** list where sensorsId property exists in sId list?

Comment: Basically the same question as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18895751/993547), and [many other questions here](https://www.google.com/search?q=subtract+list+linq+c%23&oq=subtract+list+linq+c%23#q=subtract+list+linq+c%23+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Any` with it like:

```
 desc.RemoveAll(obj => sId.Any(x=> x== obj.sensorId ));
```

As method name suggests it would check if any of the item in `sId` matches with the item in `desc` against `sensorId`, it will remove those items from `List<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for post.What if I  desc is type of IEnumarable<SDesc> and not List<SDesc>.what is the way to remove items from it?

Comment: in that case you would need to use `Where()` to filter the results and store reference to new `IEnumberable` something like: `var result = desc.Where(obj => sId.Any(x=> x== obj.sensorId ));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.Contains()` LINQ method to check if a collection contains an item:

```
desc.RemoveAll(obj => sId.Contains(obj.sensorId));
```

However, it would lead to multiple enumeration of enumerable `sId`. It's not a problem in this case since this enumerable is an array **in this particular case**.

Read more about "possible multiple enumeration":
- [Handling warning for possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240844/handling-warning-for-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable)
- [Resharper's example code for explaining "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129079/resharpers-example-code-for-explaining-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienume)

I would recommend converting it to a collection to make sure you enumerate `IEnumerable` only once.
As suggested by Evk in comments, it is better to use `HashSet` so that `.Contains` executes in `O(1)` time:

```
List<SDesc> desc = new List<SDesc> {
  new SDesc {sensorId = "1234", address =   "Adams22"},
  new SDesc {sensorId = "5555", address =   "Hourton34"},
  new SDesc {sensorId = "4444", address =   "SaintsRoad55"},
  new SDesc {sensorId = "1258", address =   "BerryAve58"},
  new SDesc {sensorId = "52486", address =   "SaintsRoad2"},
  new SDesc {sensorId = "12361", address =   "TomassonRoad"}
};

IEnumarable<string> sId = {"4444","52486","12361"};
var sIdsSet = new HashSet(sId);

desc.RemoveAll(obj => sIdsSet.Contains(obj.sensorId));
```

Comment: If convert it to anything, I'd say it should be `HashSet` and not array.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev: shouldn't you remove negator (!) from your line:  `desc.RemoveAll(x => !sIdsArray.Contains(x.sensorId));` Michael needs everything that's not in sId List

Comment: @Evk Thank you! I missed that performance improvement possibility :) Just have updated my answer.