# How to get the "leftover" records after a Linq Join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am joining two list of objects into a new list using some criteria. After the join, what's the best way to get the remaining items not in the join?

```
//line is an internal object, not important here
List<Line> main = ReadMainLines(); //read the main lines
List<Line> ref = ReadReferenceLines(); //read the lines that contain addtional data

IEnumerable<Line[]> result = main.Join(...);
```

I am good so far. I am using the result to do some additional processing. My challenge is to get the rest of the lines from main that's not in the joined result. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your full join? You may be able to just select the records opposite of the condition(s) to get the leftovers.

Comment: You could use a [left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) instead, then the rows with a value for `reference` are what you have now (an inner join) and the ones with nulls are the rest.

Comment: I am having problem posting codes ... I've looked at the left outer join option and researching it. My challenge is the result variable is of type IEnumerable<Line[]>, there are multiple Line objects inside the IEnumerable variable. I only need to search the first Line object in that Line[], how do I do that in Linq?

Comment: Use the First() method.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want what is in `ref` but not in `main`, you can use `.Except` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895751/subtract-a-generic-list-from-another).

`ref.Except(main)` - If you want the opposite, then it's just `main.Except(ref)`.
Now, you will need to write a [IEquatableComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) for type `Line`.

Also, don't use `ref` as a variable name, it's a keyword in C#.