# Joining a list of classes

Tags: linq, class, join

Hi guys i have two lists of the class Student

```
List<Student> group1= new List<Trade>();
List<Student> group2= new List<Trade>();
public class Student
        {
            public string First_Name{ get; set; }
            public string Surname{ get; set; }
            public string Age{ get; set; }
        }
```

i would like to do a join that enables me to see those that are only in 1 group.
ideal output being a datatable with column 1 showing those that only in group1 and column2 representing those only in group2
any help would be really appreciated.  I am struggling to get my head around joins

Comment: You can't assign the `List` of `Trade` to `List` of `Student`.

Comment: You probably don't need a join here, which is probably why you're having trouble understanding how to do the join. I would wager that Rahul's answer is what you need, making this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18099054/397817 . Also: in a large school it would not be at all unusual to have two students with the same forename, surname and age. You should consider assigning a unique ID to each student.

Comment: yes i have applied Rahuls answer to good effect using a unique string ID. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):-

```
var onlyInGroup1 = group1.Except(group2);
var onlyInGroup2 = group2.Except(group1);
```

Please note, since Student is a complex type, you need to implement `IEqualityComparer<Student>`.

Also, I missed your list initialization, as pointed by @Hamlet, it should be something like this:-

```
List<Student> group1= new List<Student>();
List<Student> group2= new List<Student>();
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul - perhaps i didn't explain correctly.  i want to do a full join on the two lists and get the differences

Comment: @Jon - Why you need `Join` here? Can you show any sample input\output you are expecting?

Comment: thanks a lot just looking at IEqualityComparer<Student>.  The Except worked great when i built strings of the info as opposed to classes.

Comment: @You in case of strings, default comparer will be used, you need to implement `IEqualityComparer` yourself for complex types such as Student.

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate thru group1 and see if group2 contains a match to group1

```
foreach (Student student in group1)
 {
  if (group2.Contains(student.First_Name))
   {
    //logic goes here
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  a loop was going to be my plan B.  was hoping a method existed that would crunch the data.

Comment: there probably is...I just don't know what it is!